# Getting Failure of Compactness from the Failure of Upward Lowenheim-Skolem in Omega logic.

Tags: model-theory

(1)Given Omega-completeness, and assuming compactness implies upward Lowenheim-Skolem, can one get the failure of compactness by showing failure of upward l.s.? I ask because it would seem to take care of "two birds with one stone". (2) *if* one can proceed in this way, is my proof sketch below correct?

My proof sketch would be as follows:

Claim: Compactness and upward l.s. fails in Omega logic.

Proof: Suppose Omega-logic is complete. We show that upward l.s. fails by constructing a sentence which characterizes Omega logic and which has only countable models. Then for a given T characterizing Omega logic, T has a model. So by the Omega rule we can construct a countably infinite conjunction PHI s.t. T|- PHI. By completeness PHI must have a model, so |= PHI. Now since there are only Omega-many constants in the model, PHI can only have a countable model. Now compactness implies upward l.s.; upward fails, so compactness fails as well.

Comment: What is Omega logic? Do you mean $L_{\omega_1,\omega}$?

Comment: Yes, I do mean that.

Comment: I don't really understand what is $T$ and how is $\Phi$ related to it. Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Also, it doesn't really answer your question, but to show that L-S fails you can just use the sentence $\forall x \bigvee x=c_n$, and to show that compactness fails you can the previous sentence and the formulas $x\neq c_n$.

Comment: Thanks, tomasz - if I understand correctly, you're taking an infinite disjunction satisfied in a model having omega-many distinct elements, but no more, and upward l.s. fails?

Comment: Yes, and when you take this and formulas that say that an element is distinct from each $c_n$ you get a contradiction, even though any finite subset is consistent, so compactness fails.

Comment: Got it - thanks!